# Resending Notification on error in Error Reporting

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-error-reporting

This is regarding re-sending of notifications on error of same kind.
In my current project, my errors are being grouped.

Like for eg: If it is an sql error for first time, I receive a notification but when it occurs after 2 or 3 hours it is grouped under same log and 'no notification is sent'.

**On what basis does error reporting group the erorrs ?**

I tried to randomise the error message in order to distinguish messages but still they are being grouped under the same category. (For eg: messages be like - service unavailable - 12, service unavailable - 23 etc.. )

I want to receive notification for each and every error irrespective of its type or repitition. 
Suggest a solution ?

Comment: Here's how error grouping works: https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/grouping Based on this, there's no real control given to the user to ungroup errors with similar stack traces.

Comment: Do the errors contain a stack trace?

Comment: Yes.. for each sql error .. it is printed in logs.. and error is also reported but no mails received for repeating errors !

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is alerting based on a log based metric: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/charts-and-alerts#creating_a_simple_alerting_policy_on_a_counter_metric

Comment: So how does this help in my case.. if I want to receive mails for each and every error irrespective of its type (whether same type as previous error or not). ?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I see the same, I can get the incidents based on a log metric fine, but for some cases I need notifications for all occurrences of the same incident.

i.e. if you just looking for a message in a log, and do a metric on count, not only its not firing multiple emails, but its never auto closing this (except after 7 days) so I also doesn't create a new incident ever it seems :/